# Android: How to add color fade-in animation for custom button

Tags: android, animation, button, transition

I have made an xml specifying 2 states for a button (pressed and non-pressed states). The pressed button has a color filled in, while the non-pressed button has a border with some text in it. How can I make the non-pressed button fade into the pressed button when the user touches it and revert back to the non-pressed button as soon as the user releases the button?

EDIT:

It seems that most of the answers did not exactly solve my problem and although the transitiondrawable seems like it could work, I don't know how to implement it with my current code.

To clarify further, the following is my code for a button stored in the drawable folder named button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/buttonpressed"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/buttonnormal"
        android:state_enabled="true"/>

</selector>
```

I have already referenced the drawable xml in my main xml file.

I want to be able to fade from "buttonnormal" to "buttonpressed" when the button is pressed and revert back to "buttonnormal" when the button is released.

Answer (score 6):

Use ObjectAnimator

```
int colorFrom = 0xaaaaaaaa;
int colorTo = 0xffFFFFFF;
int duration = 500;
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(myButton, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo)

anim.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        // Trigger the events after animation is ended
    }
   @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
});
anim.setDuration(duration).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a 3rd xml file, say `button_bg.xml`, with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal"></item>

</selector>
```

where `pressed.xml` and `normal.xml` are your xmls with the color filled in and otherwise, respectively. Now set the above xml as the background of the button.

```
         <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its little late now but, you can add from following steps:

1. Add the below colour values to the colors.xml located in res ⇒ values ⇒ colors.xml.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

   `<resources>`

   `<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>`

   `<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>`

   `<color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>`

   `<!-- Gradient color -->`

   `<color name="colorPurple_A400">#D500F9</color>`

   `<color name="colorPurple_900">#4A148C</color>`

`</resources>`

2. Add below line in your styles.xml file:

   `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`
3. Add the drawable for this gradient: [Make a file in the drawable folder like eg: **gradient.xml** and add these lines...]

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

`<gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@color/colorPurple_A400"
        android:startColor="@color/colorPurple_900" />`
`</shape>`

4. Make a file called anime_list.xml inside the drawable folder and add these lines:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

`<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

`<item
        android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_purple_gradient"
        android:duration="6000" />`

`</animation-list>`

Now add this **anime_list.xml** as background of main root-layout element like:

```
android:background="@drawable/anime_list"
```

5. In MainActivity.java file add these modifications:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
private AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    // init constraintLayout
    constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);

    // initializing animation drawable by getting background from constraint layout
    animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) constraintLayout.getBackground();

    // setting enter fade animation duration to 5 seconds
    animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(5000);

    // setting exit fade animation duration to 2 seconds
    animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(2000);
}
}
```

And you are good to go...

Reference: [animated-gradient-background-in-android](http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/animated-gradient-background-in-android/)